# pass QueryString using RewriteRule in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a profile page and I am using the profile GUID as id in the QueryString which means it has all type of characters.

I am currently using:

**profile?id=347692ca-47a8-11e3-bea0-782bcb3e3838**

I want it be:

**profile/347692ca-47a8-11e3-bea0-782bcb3e3838**

I tried this but didn't work:

**RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ profile.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]**

can you please help...

.....

Thanks

[Jassim](http://www.xoompage.com)

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you getting 404? Do you have .htaccess and mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: This might be an issue with the fact that you are using `.htaccess` style files to place the rewriting. That makes rules more complex to setup. If possible, always use the real http server configuration. `.htaccess` style files are only a last resort, should only be used if there is a real reason for that. They slow everything down and are much harder to debug.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Please add more information to your question.

Comment: This is the code I am using and it's going to the home page which means it didn't determine the querystring: if ($mysql_row_count <= 0) { exit(header("Location: " . $_SESSION["domain_name"] . "home")); }

Comment: and yes I am using the htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: (tested in Debian/Apache2) in /.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^profile/?([^/]*)$ /profile.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^profile/?([^/]*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The slash / prefix is required.

Comment: same problem. It's working on my localhost but when I upload it to the host it will not work. check it here with id= and without. http://www.xoompage.com/profile?id=347692ca-47a8-11e3-bea0-782bcb3e3838 my .htaccess has Options All -Indexes and RewriteEngine On and RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d   and RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f